# Spatial join point data to polygon shapefile and count a variable

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-join, arcgis-10.3

I would like to perform a spatial join from point data to a polygon shapefile.  In the point data attribute table there is a column called {quality} and I would like to count each category from the column: {High, Medium, Low}.  This would be the same as running a Pivot Table in Excel.

I am using ArcGIS 10.3

Comment: Would you like to make a spatial join (based on location) or just a join (based on a common attribute in 2 tables)? This is not clear in your question.

Comment: Okay, I have a shapefile with point data that is being displayed on to of another shapefile that has polygons.  The point data shapefile's attribute table has a column called {quality} which can either be {High, Medium, Low}.

I want to spatially join the point data to the polygon shapefile.  When I do it counts the number of points per polygon.  I would like to count the number or points per polygon but also the number of {quality} categories counted in separate columns so that I know how many {High, Medium, Low} points are in each polygon.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using ArcGIS 9/10x the standard "Spatial Join" tool (ArcToolbox > Analysis Tools > Overlay> Spatial Join) will stamp your polygon category's on your quality points (as an out feature class). Where there is no intersecting category polygon the values will be null. After this you can use a statistics tool to get numeric statistics.

[image: Spatial Join Example]